# ubuntu 20.04 7z command on bash script

Tags: bash, 7zip

I'm using this script to shortcut a 7z command with prefered options:

```
#!/bin/bash

7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -ms=on -mmt=on "$1".7z $2
```

If I give it a folder as the second argument it work just fine, but if I send something like `*file*.png`, it creates the 7z files but there is nothing on it... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please read the information pertaining to your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, and [edit] your question to clarify whether this is in fact for a [[tag:unix]] based [[tag:bash]] [[tag:shell]] script, with a .[[tag:sh]] extension, or for a [[tag:windows]] script intended to be ran with [[tag:cmd]].exe?

Comment: the title says ubuntu...

Comment: yeah, I read it in a hurry, edited.

Comment: you should try to use `'*file*.png'`. I mean with the use of 2 ' (simple quote) chars.

Comment: @kurokirasama: super. The real solution is to use `$#` and `shift` and `"${@}"` within your script. There is some information in the `man bash`: look for the `positional parameters`

Answer (score 0):

When pressing [Enter] key after writing the script name and its parameters in the terminal, the current bash is expanding the `*file*.png`: it is replaced by the list of the files found on the disk, and then the script is run.

So, `$2` is the first file from the list of the files found by the shell after `*file.*.png` was expanded: see `PARAMETERS` and `Special Parameters` and `pathname expansion` in the `man bash`.

As wrote in the comment, a quick win, using the same script, unchanged, is to prevent the pathname expansion using 2 `'` chars in the command line:

```
$ my-7z.sh png-files '*file*.png'
```

The definitive solution, is to handle the `positional parameters`:

```
#!/bin/bash

7z_filename="${1}".7z
shift

7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -ms=on -mmt=on "${7z_filename}" "${@}"
```

Maybe it is worth to check the positional parameters, to add some error management.

Comment: I got this error: `line 6: ${7z_filename}: bad substitution`